# How to create dynamically generated slides from an array in a looped Swiper.js slide

Tags: slider, svelte, swiper.js

I have a slider where I need the slides to be dynamically generated (a calendar a component, specifically). I want no more than 3 slides in the DOM at any one point, and as the user swipes next/prev, the slides should reflect this.

For simplicity I've created a minimal version in Svelte's REPL in the hope that someone can help me figure out how to update the array. Swiper's `loop` function seems to make the slides jump around, so I can't quite figure out:

1. Which Swiper method to hook into; and
2. How best to update the array when swiping forward and back

[Here's the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/dbed197236f4448c87cdb6b548a3e8b7?version=3.48.0)

And here's the code from the REPL:

```
<script>
    import { register } from 'swiper@latest/element/bundle';
    register();

    let slides = [50, 51, 52];
    let swiper;
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        Slides array:
        {#each slides as slide}
            ({slide})
        {/each}
    </div>

    <swiper-container
        bind:this={swiper}
        loop={true}
        slides-per-view={1}
        on:loopfix={() => {
            const i = swiper.swiper.activeIndex;

            if (i == 1) {
                const currSlide = slides[i];
                slides[(i + 1) % 3] = currSlide + 1;
            }
        }}
    >
        {#each slides as item}
            <swiper-slide>
                Slide {item}
            </swiper-slide>
        {/each}
    </swiper-container>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 40em;
    }

    swiper-container {
        border: 2px solid lightgray;
    }

    swiper-slide {
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

I've tried running different functions in different events such as `slideChange`, `slideNextTransitionEnd` and `reachEnd` , but can't figure it out. I've also tried `observeUpdate` parameter, but that didn't seem to help.